# mp4 video not playing from url in pbjvideoplayer

Tags: iphone, ios8, avplayer

Hello guys I have used the library `pbjvideoplayer` for playing videos from URLs. The mp4 video is playing on iOS > 8 and not playing on iOS < 8.

video url = http://ivoiceup.com/wework/message_uploads/82208897ae4f9b7d64a50bc70c6cf0a3.mp4